Sonar stats - Line is hit by the unit tests but still displayed as uncovered
Sonar web frontend shows displays the line as uncovered, while it's hit by at least one unit test (we temporarily put an exception inside the condition and it's thrown, so we know for sure that's it's executed by the unit test). Sorry for a vague description, but how do we investigate the issue futher?
//c#
if (condition)
{
  do() // the line is hit by the unit test but still treated as uncovered by Sonar
}

